# Segmentation fault after using for loop

Tags: c++, string, stl, segmentation-fault, getline

Below is my code.It runs perfectly fine if I comment the for loop but when I add the for loop , it gives a segmentation fault and even the code before the for loop doesn't show any output.
If there is something wrong in the for loop then it should at least show some output before loop starts.
Also here I am using getline because my string contains white spaces.
P.S. My mistake is in the loop that my I may be more than string length but what does it have to do with segmentation fault before loop starts ,it should at least print the length.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,s,'\n');
        int len=s.length();
        cout<<len;
        int curr_len=0;
        int prev_len=0;;
        int count=1;
        int max=1;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            cout<<s[i];
            while(s[i]!=' ')
            {
                curr_len=curr_len+1;
                i=i+1;
            }
            if(curr_len==prev_len)
            {
                count=count+1;
                if(count>max)
                    max=count;
            }
            else
            {
                count=1;
            }
            while(s[i]==' ')
            {
                i=i+1;
                prev_len=curr_len;
                curr_len=0;
            }
        }
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: "If there is something wrong in the for loop then it should at least show some output before loop starts." actually the standard doesn't require that, it's the magic of undefined behaviour (but in this case, it might be because the cout buffer has not been flushed yet)

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Writing loops like this is rarely necessary in C++ -- more than likely an algorithm or set of algorithm functions would do the job, resulting in much less code.  Second, you increment `i` inside the loop without checking if it has gone beyond the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in that you are not testing for `i` going out of bounds in your nested `while` loops:

For example:

```
  while (s[i] != ' ')
```

Should be:

```
  while (s[i] != ' ' && i < len)
```

Assume that `i` is almost at the end of your input string, and there are no more space characters in the input string starting at where `i` is pointing to.  This `while` loop will keep going until it finds a space character.  That could be many hundreds, maybe thousands of bytes beyond the length of the string.

Once you apply this change to this while loop and all the others where you are not doing this check, the program should run (whether the results are correct or not is a different story).

Answer (score 2):

```
while(s[i]!=' ')
  {
       curr_len=curr_len+1;
       i=i+1;
  }
```

I think that this is your problem.
think what happens when s[i] is the end of the line.

Comment: I have edited the question.That it should print len atleast so far I think .

Comment: @facebook-100003312828525 see my comment on your question, `std::cout` doesn't flush the buffer each time you try to write something.

Comment: Thanks @ Caninonos. I have used cin.ignore() to clear any buffer.

Comment: I was thinking of something more like `std::cout << len << std::flush;` i don't think `std::cin::ignore` flushes `std::cout`'s buffer

Comment: @facebook-100003312828525: `cin.ignore()` has nothing to do with "clearing any buffer" ("clearing" is the opposite of "flushing", anyway) and it has nothing to do with `std::cout`. Your `len` was stuck in `std::cout`'s buffer and your program never got a chance to perform its automatic flushing because it crashed first.

Comment: Got it.Thanks a lot @Caninonos and Lightness Races in Orbit. Also can you provide some useful link to read about these.

Comment: [about undefined behaviour](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) (always good to know), i don't have any link about flushing one's streams in mind (once you know that it's buffered, you know that sometimes the stream might not be flushed and there's pretty much nothing more to say about it), however you can still read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp or http://www.cplusplus.com/ pages when you're unsure of some standard library's class/method/function behaviour